# Mysql Select vs Select SUM performance

Tags: mysql, select, performance, sum, performance-testing

I need to check whether the surfer has alrady voted this can be done using

Method 1

```
Select record_num FROM table where etc etc.
```

i.e.

```
SELECT record_num
FROM content_votes_tmp 
WHERE up = 1
AND ip = INET_ATON('$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]') 
AND content = $_POST[id]
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) > '$old_time'
```

Method 2

```
Select Sum(votes) FROM table where etc etc.
```

i.e.

```
SELECT SUM(up) as up_count
FROM content_votes_tmp 
WHERE ip = INET_ATON('$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]') 
AND content = $_POST[id]
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) > '$old_time'
```

Using storage engine as MyISAM ,
Table has around 1 million rows,
ROW Format  is static.

I am looking for query which is faster in terms of performance.

So which query will be faster ? this query will be fired every time someone clicks the vote up or vote down button.,

---

here is a table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_votes_tmp` (
  `up` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `down` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_updated` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `record_num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`record_num`)
  KEY `content` (`content`),
  KEY `datetime` (`datetime`),
  KEY `is_updated` (`is_updated`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```

Comment: Can you provide a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a more complete query (even if you rename columns to col1, col2, etc. for privacy)? We need more details to see if indexes are going to be helpful.

Comment: @jynus please check the updated question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 queries that you show are different in meaning.

**The first one** will select all upvotes for that ip and content in that timeframe. If you create the index:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE content_votes_tmp ADD INDEX(up, ip, content, datetime, record_num);
Query OK, 753676 rows affected (3.85 sec)
Records: 753676  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

You can get good performance results- the first 2 columns will be used and you will get the Using Index optimization:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT record_num 
               FROM content_votes_tmp  
               WHERE up = 1 AND 
                     ip = 1  AND 
                     content = 1 AND 
                     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) > @number\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: content_votes_tmp
         type: ref
possible_keys: up
          key: up
      key_len: 12
          ref: const,const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

We can do even better than that. Remove the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function -compare dates instead of ints by transforming $old_time- and will be able to apply all conditions using the index (3 consts and 1 range):

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT record_num 
               FROM content_votes_tmp  
               WHERE up = 1 AND 
                     ip = 1  AND 
                     content = 1 AND 
                     datetime > now()\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: content_votes_tmp
         type: range
possible_keys: up
          key: up
      key_len: 17
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Be careful if the logic of the application requires to know if a downvote was done, this query will not help you with that.

**The second one** will require a slightly different index:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE content_votes_tmp ADD INDEX(ip, content, datetime, up);
Query OK, 753676 rows affected (5.95 sec)
Records: 753676  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

In order to get a good query plan, also needing the "move the function to the other side of the operand":

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(up) as up_count 
       FROM content_votes_tmp  
       WHERE ip = 1 AND 
             content = 1 AND 
             datetime > now()\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: content_votes_tmp
         type: range
possible_keys: ip
          key: ip
      key_len: 13
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**I do not like the range + SUM(), so I would prefer the first one, which is simpler** (unless you intend to return lots of rows). **But there is nothing on the query plan to support my fears** (it has the covering index optimization too, and no filesort, so both can be very fast with the appropriate indexes- they take 0.00s with my fake 1M data).

Remember that the logic is slightly different, so be aware of that- if you allowed upvotes and downvotes, that could be a problem.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation , i am allowing upvotes and downvotes too including undo upvotes and undo downvotes...